# serialize() and $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, serialization

Once the user is authenticated, I serialized the class object and stored it in a session. However, I cant seem to print its output even after using unserialize().

**Creating the session variable:**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['myObj']) && empty($_SESSION['myObj'])) {
$myObj = new User($row['user_id'], $row['username'], $row['user_level']);
$_SESSION['username']= $myObj->usr_name;
$s_Obj = serialize($myObj);
$_SESSION['myObj'] = $s_Obj;
```

**Accessing from a different page, no output:**

```
$sObj = $_SESSION['Obj'];
$myObj = unserialize($s_Obj);
echo $myObj->usr_name;
```

This works however, so there's nothing wrong with my class. I am also using `session_start()` in both pages.

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

**Class user:**

```
<?php 

class User{
    public $usr_id;
    public $usr_name;
    public $usr_level;
    public $last_access_login;

    public function __construct($id, $usr_name, $usr_level) {
        $this->usr_id = $id;
        $this->usr_name = $usr_name;
        $this->usr_level = $usr_level;
        $this->last_access_login = date("F d Y H:i:s.",time());
  }
}
?>
```

Edit:

This is my vardump

```
array
  'myObj' => 
    object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)[1]
      public '__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name' => string 'User' (length=4)
      public 'usr_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'usr_name' => string 'student' (length=7)
      public 'usr_level' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'last_access_login' => string 'November 26 2011 20:12:38.' (length=26)
  'url' => string '/researchportal/proposal' (length=24)
```

Comment: Did you use `session_start()` on all of your pages? And what does `User()` look like?

Comment: `$_SESSION['myObj'] = $myObj` should be enough, I think -- PHP should handle the serialization for you.

Comment: @lonsesomeday I also tried that, but it didnt work.

Comment: There is no point in serializing data, then storing it in a session. Session data is implicitly serialized, you are just adding processing overhead. Just do `$_SESSION['myObj'] = $myObj`. This may or may not fix the problem - it's just general advice. Not that you would need to include the file that contains the class `User` *before* calling session_start().

Comment: Always turn turn up error reporting to the max when developing. Then var_dump($_SESSION); Then read about defining classes *before* calling session_Start()

Comment: Duplicates "[PHP Session with an Incomplete Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1055728/90527)", "[PHP __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object with my $_SESSION data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2010427/90527)", "[Storing A PHP Object In A Session Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2042271/90527)", "[Problem with PHP Session Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5348457/90527)" and others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inital page:

```
$s_Obj = serialize($myObj);
$_SESSION['myObj'] = $s_Obj;
```

should be

```
$_SESSION['myObj'] = $myObj;
```

Next page:

```
$sObj = $_SESSION['Obj'];
$myObj = unserialize($s_Obj);
```

should be

```
$myObj = $_SESSION['myObj'];
```

In addition, try declaring your classes before your call to `session_start()`.

Comment: I also fixed this mistake. But still its not working.

Comment: @user478636 How about the updated code?

Comment: try to analyze with var_dump. Did you ever try to var_dump($_SESSION); ?

Comment: @Marko Well, it appears that `echo $_SESSION['username'];` works, so `$_SESSION` should be working fine.

Comment: Hmm i tried it but no luck. Why does `$_SESSION['username']=$myObj->usr_name;` work but not `$_SESSION['myObj']=$myObj;`

Comment: @user478636 Did you declare your classes before `session_start()`?

Comment: The problem was that I was declaring Class `User` after session_start();

Answer (score 3):

Your unserialized object is being unserialized as an instance of `__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name` because you are not including the definition of the User class prior to unserializing it. See [Object Serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php). You must include the definition of the User class before you try to unserialize it.